# How to change a particular value in a JSON file in a bash script?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
{
  "A": {
    "i": "user_defined",
    "j": 678,
    "k": 1.75,
    "l": 6.7,
    "m": 1.2
  },
  "W": "10",
  "counter": {
    "0": {
      "p": 34,
      "q": "returned",
      "r": 98,
      "s": "wait",
      "t": "done",
      "u": "8.9"
    }
  },
  "z": "th"
}
```

I want in each round of a loop of 10 rounds, the key in the value of "counter" (which is 0 now) to get changed to the number of the loop. This means if it is the first round of the loop the above file should be changed to:

```
{
  "A": {
    "i": "user_defined",
    "j": 678,
    "k": 1.75,
    "l": 6.7,
    "m": 1.2
  },
  "W": "10",
  "counter": {
    "1": {
      "p": 34,
      "q": "returned",
      "r": 98,
      "s": "wait",
      "t": "done",
      "u": "8.9"
    }
  },
  "z": "th"
}
```

and if it is the 8th round of the loop, it will be:

```
{
  "A": {
    "i": "user_defined",
    "j": 678,
    "k": 1.75,
    "l": 6.7,
    "m": 1.2
  },
  "W": "10",
  "counter": {
    "8": {
      "p": 34,
      "q": "returned",
      "r": 98,
      "s": "wait",
      "t": "done",
      "u": "8.9"
    }
  },
  "z": "th"
}
```

Also, in each round, the previous JSON file will be overwritten by the current round. I tried the following code but it didn't change anything:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read initial JSON content from file
initial_json=$(cat config.json)

# Loop for 10 rounds
for round in {1..10}; do
  # Modify JSON content
  modified_json=$(echo "$initial_json" | jq --argjson round "$round" '.counter = {($round|tostring): .counter."0"}')

  # Write modified JSON back to the file
  echo "$modified_json" > config.json

  echo "Round $round: JSON updated"
done
```

How to fix the code?

Comment: So you want a single file containing those 10 objects? Or an array holding the 10 objects?

Comment: @0stone0 A single file that is overwritten 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

The key can be changed using the following JQ filter:

```
jq '.counter |= with_entries(.key = "5")' input.json
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LI5Mh8UQxn2)

---

Then, using a bash loop where we append all 10 objects to a new file, use:

```bash
for round in {1..10}; do 
    jq --arg counter "$round" '.counter |= with_entries(.key = $counter)' input.json >> output.txt
done
```

This will generate `output.txt` and will append all 10 objects to it.

---

If you don't really need bash, you can use `range(10)` to let JQ do the looping, use the same filter as above and if needed, wrap it in an array, a single file with the 10 objects could be generated using:

```
jq 'range(10) as $n | .counter |= with_entries(.key = "\($n)")' input.json
```

This uses `range(10)` and sets it to the `.key` using `|=`. Using [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) to convert the integers to strings. This approach is a lot more efficient since we don't need to remember the original object. Thanks to [@pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883696/how-to-change-a-particular-value-in-a-json-file-in-a-bash-script?noredirect=1#comment135539846_76883858) for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: To just increment, perhaps `.counter |= with_entries(.key = (.key | tonumber + 1 | tostring))`

Comment: If you make `range(10) | tostring` a clause on its own (either by enclosing it in parentheses `(range(10) | tostring) as $n`, or by replacing `tostring` with string interpolation `"\(range(10))" as $n`), you can omit saving the `$original` input (which would get lost if `range` was in the main clause): `jq '"\(range(10))" as $n | .counter |= with_entries(.key = $n)' input.json` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/R5kRlh09yWG). Or move the string conversion also inside the loop: `jq 'range(10) as $n | .counter |= with_entries(.key = "\($n)")' input.json` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/opWHYHF90A9)